# When I select the dataframe "emp.data B" in R shiny, how do I render a heading/tag as "Summary"?

Tags: r, shiny, rscript, rshiny

I'm making R shiny app to generate data frames based on choosing. Only after selecting the data frame emp.data_B I want to present a header text like "Summary." How to do this?

Below is my code:

```
library(shiny)

emp.data_A <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:5),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25))
  
emp.data_A


emp.data_B <- data.frame(
  emp_id = c(1:7),
  emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary", "Vicky", "Armstrong"),
  salary = c(623.3,515.2,611.0,729.0,843.25, 845.90, 852.20))
emp.data_B


shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      selectInput("dataset5", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "emp.data_A", "emp.data_B")),
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table5")
  )
),

server = function(input, output,session) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset5,
           "emp.data_A" = emp.data_A,
           "emp.data_B" = emp.data_B)
  })
  output$table5 <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })

}
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `uiOutput` and show it conditionally.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      
      selectInput("dataset5", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "emp.data_A", "emp.data_B")),
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData5", "Download")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("header"),
      tableOutput("table5")
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset5,
             "emp.data_A" = emp.data_A,
             "emp.data_B" = emp.data_B)
    })
    output$table5 <- renderTable({
      datasetInput()
    })
    
    output$header <- renderUI({
      if(input$dataset5 == "emp.data_B") 
        tags$pre(h4("Summary Extraction \t \t VS \t \t Extraction Summary" ))
    })
    
  }
)
```

Comment: It works well, I need extra tab spaces between words in the header like "Summary       vs       Calculation"? how it should be done.

Comment: `if(input$dataset5 == "emp.data_B") "Summary vs Calculation"` ?

Comment: how to implement this -> tags$pre(h4("Summary Extraction  \t \t VS \t \t    Extraction Summary" ))  as a header conditionally

Comment: @ Ronak Shah, Any suggestions?